# Python - save x values from a column to list when a number in another column is bigger than the number before

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, overlap

(I'm new to this so I might not know the best way to formulate this question but here goes)

I'm using **pandas** btw!

I am looking for a construct to each time save x values (let's say x=3 so three values) from **one column to a list** when a number in another column is bigger than the number before. First number should not be considered. Important to note that there are also missing data in the number column (NaN).

```
NumberColumn   Value
23             4
23             5
NaN            8
24             6    # <--
24             23   # <--
24             26   # <--
24             11
25             2    # <--
25             1    # <--
25             3    # <--
25             5
Nan            9
26             4    # <--
26             6    # <--
NaN            9    # <--
26             12
```

Hopefully in the end the new list contains:

```
List1 = [6,23,26,2,1,3,4,6,9]
```

But also they might overlap so:

```
NumberColumn       Value
    27             4
    28             5    # <--
    NaN            8    # <--
    29             6    # <--   <-- overlap!
    29             23         # <--
    29             26         # <--
```

Hopefully here the list will contain:

```
List1 = [5, 8, 6, 6, 23, 26]
```

Thanks for helping me out !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the assumption that numbers cannot be smaller than 0:

```
list1 = []
x=3

df.fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    if df.loc[i, 'NumberColumn']>df.loc[i-1, 'NumberColumn']:
        list1 = list1 + df.loc[i:i+x-1, 'Value'].values.tolist()
print(list1)
```

As a function:

```
def createList(df, x):
    list1 = []
    df.fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
    for i in range(1, len(df)):
        if df.loc[i, 'NumberColumn']>df.loc[i-1, 'NumberColumn']:
            list1 = list1 + df.loc[i:i+x-1, 'Value'].values.tolist()
    return list1

list1 = createList(df, x=3)
print(list1)
```